# Is there a way to see a Stack Exchange site's oldest users?

Tags: discussion, search, users

In the 'Users' section of each Stack Exchange site, there is a 'New User' section that shows the newest members of the site. But, is there any good way to see the oldest members of each site?

I have found that when I type, for example, `user:1` into the main search tab on this site, that it pulls up a post by Jeff Atwood, which means that he was the 1st user on this site (right?). But after `user:4` (the four users that show up using the search tab are all moderators that work on the SO team), the method doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This query will grab the 100 oldest users on a site ordered by their id

```
SELECT TOP 100 
id as [User Link]
From Users
where id != -1
ORDER BY id`
```

[Link to query](https://data.stackexchange.com/outdoors/query/882054)

or by their creation date

```
SELECT TOP 100 
id as [User Link]
From Users
where id != -1
ORDER BY creationdate
```

[Link to query](https://data.stackexchange.com/outdoors/query/882055)

You can use the site switcher below the Run Query button to switch to the desired site,

Comment: As per the OP's question,  it might be more accurate to `order by CreationDate`, as they don't seem convinced/sure that `id` always means older user.

Comment: @DavyM I added a query that sorts by that, I don't see a difference in the results but its there now

Comment: Interesting, I haven't seen that page before. So I guess that `user:1` doesn't necessarily mean they were first, right?

Comment: Shouldn't you filter out the Community user? It's not really a user so it doesn't really make sense to say that it's the first user.

Comment: @DonaldDuck Yeah, that makes sense.

Comment: @DonaldDuck Done

Comment: @LAD Each time a record is inserted into the table, the value of the id is one more than the value of the id in the preceding row. So perhaps the most accurate way of putting it, is that sorting by id shows the order in which they were inserted into the DB

Comment: @CharlieBrumbaugh Cool, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: There are a few cases where [id's and createddate have a different order](https://data.stackexchange.com/avp/query/882138). I used the site Audio Video production because I know that site has been merged (former Audio.SE and Video.se) so I expected to find a lot of these case but that doesn't hold. The few cases you see are probably caused by account merges but only a mod or SE staff can confirm

Comment: [Glorfindel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/295232/glorfindel) was kind enough to [check](https://data.stackexchange.com/apple/query/882161) and confirmed most of my hypothesis [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/45976441#45976441) where he notes that small differences in creationdates don't involve account merges. They can be written off on race-conditions.